# Cannot use layout_alignParentTop among others in autocomplete

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am wanting to use autocomplete in android studio but it does not work for all code options. I cannot get autocomplete for TextView.setText, for layout_alignParentTop and a lot of other things. I looked at other questions but their's is only for xml tab. Mine is for the whole project.

With the text I am typing, before I finish typing it I get a red error:
missing value validates resource references inside android xml files

If you see the image there is no option for android:layout_alignParentTop

[image]

Comment: what you try so far ? code please

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the view group you are using. The layout parameter you're intending to use belongs to a specific view group hence autocomplete isn't showing you that option.

I recommend reading on [View Groups](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) and [Layout Parameters](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params)

Your text view has to be inside the relative layout group like so

```
<RelativeLayout
    //codes >
   <TexView
       android:layout_ //you should already see suggestions here />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean I have to import ViewGroup? I did that and it still does not show up in autocomplete.

Comment: See edited answer. As stated, it's best to refer to the documentation to see which layout parameter belongs to which view group.